# Parse Dashboard

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, dashboard, parse-server

I implemented Parse Dashboard on Heroku server using this article: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/

http://localhost:4040 and it ran perfectly the first time. The problem now i restarted the computer and i tried to access it again from the same link but i cannot reach the website? So i was wondering how to solve that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i have to run "npm run dashboard" each time i open the URL.